# Kernel panics due to Parallels Desktop or Apple's own problem with graphics controller?

Tags: high-sierra, kernel-panic, parallels-desktop, kernel, kernel-extensions

Twice this week my MacBook Pro Retina has suffered kernel panics for the first time after years of faithful service.

This coincides with me upgrading and beginning to use [Parallels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac) 14.0.1, so I wonder if there is a connection. But I do not see Parallels mentioned in the backtrace. I see only [IOKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_Kit) and graphics-related extensions. But I am no expert in reading backtraces.

➥ Should I remove Parallels from my machine?Or should I do a clean install to rid me of Parallels entirely?

Is it possible that Parallels is unrelated, given the report below? I have been running Parallels in the background, with a VM running macOS Mojave with no apps but a [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database server running headless.

The panic report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       7988D7B5-A78C-5F21-9D9A-53ACD8B28DFE

Mon Nov  5 12:32:50 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f9d659d08): "IOAccelResource::free called for resource still owned by an IOAccelShared"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOAcceleratorFamily_kexts/IOAcceleratorFamily-378.26/Kext2/IOAccelResource.cpp:247
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9259183310 : 0xffffff801c66c1c6 
0xffffff9259183360 : 0xffffff801c795274 
0xffffff92591833a0 : 0xffffff801c787544 
0xffffff9259183410 : 0xffffff801c61e1e0 
0xffffff9259183430 : 0xffffff801c66bc3c 
0xffffff9259183560 : 0xffffff801c66b9fc 
0xffffff92591835c0 : 0xffffff7f9d659d08 
0xffffff92591835e0 : 0xffffff7f9d6faa79 
0xffffff9259183600 : 0xffffff7f9d735609 
0xffffff9259183660 : 0xffffff7f9d72e2fa 
0xffffff9259183760 : 0xffffff7f9d731ea5 
0xffffff9259183810 : 0xffffff7f9d704fa8 
0xffffff92591838c0 : 0xffffff7f9d705a72 
0xffffff92591839d0 : 0xffffff7f9d7063a1 
0xffffff9259183a20 : 0xffffff7f9d679304 
0xffffff9259183a70 : 0xffffff7f9d67910f 
0xffffff9259183ac0 : 0xffffff7f9d678302 
0xffffff9259183b00 : 0xffffff801ccc1978 
0xffffff9259183b50 : 0xffffff7f9d7042ee 
0xffffff9259183b70 : 0xffffff801ccca567 
0xffffff9259183cb0 : 0xffffff801c742bf4 
0xffffff9259183dc0 : 0xffffff801c6716e0 
0xffffff9259183e10 : 0xffffff801c64ea3d 
0xffffff9259183e60 : 0xffffff801c66154b 
0xffffff9259183ef0 : 0xffffff801c77171d 
0xffffff9259183fa0 : 0xffffff801c61e9e6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7f9d644000->0xffffff7f9d6dcfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[4FAE8181-B0B4-3A30-B0F3-77F48D2486E5]@0xffffff7f9d614000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(211.15)[37BCC686-AF99-3381-AC4F-E54A347E0F40]@0xffffff7f9d629000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7f9ce94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7f9d204000
         com.apple.GeForce(10.3.2)[5FE0FEE7-0291-309C-B94E-ED28C718384E]@0xffffff7f9d6ed000->0xffffff7f9d788fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7f9ce94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(519.20)[64AB0898-0DF1-32DF-850A-8840C3478439]@0xffffff7f9d25a000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.3.2)[6DE4BC26-EEC1-379B-AD41-532FB0A529CD]@0xffffff7f9d276000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7f9d204000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7f9d644000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x000000001c400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801c600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801c500000
System model name: MacBookPro11,3 (Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 85519397230859
last loaded kext at 79921434143361: com.parallels.kext.vnic 14.0.1 45154 (addr 0xffffff7fa009d000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 77588918888403: com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  10.3.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9f716000, size 278528)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.kext.vnic 14.0.1 45154
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    14.0.1 45154
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   14.0.1 45154
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   92
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 133
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.GeForce   10.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.01.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.70.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1241.31.1a9
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   205
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 133
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1404.3
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 680.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.3.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.20
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.20
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 262
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro11,3, BootROM MBP112.0146.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.19f12
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.31.1a9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: iPhone, Ethernet, en4
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM1024F, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: iPhone
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Yes, Parallels was hidden, running in the background, running macOS Mojave as the guest OS, with no apps but a Postgres database running headless. And, I disagree, I cannot consider two kernel panics a week tolerable.

Comment: Heck, my Hackintosh doesn't even panic at all, and I'm a heavy user. Have you tried running with the VM stopped and seeing what happens? By the way, it sounds like a server would be better for running a Postgre DB than a macOS VM on macOS.

Comment: @Manchineel Postgres on the Parallels is just for local development, not serious production work. But I am wondering if I would better off using Digital Ocean or a second little PC laptop running BSD. Parallels has always been frustratingly a 99% success with a nasty 1% problem of one kind or another.

Comment: In general Parallels isn't very stable with macOS guests (ironically). Have you considered running Postgres on native macOS? Or virtualising something like Linux Ubuntu in Parallels.
Alternatively, you could use a very simple Linux machine. Even a [37$ Raspberry Pi](https://www.amazon.com/ELEMENT-Element14-Raspberry-Pi-Motherboard/dp/B07BDR5PDW/ref=sr_1_3?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1541507721&sr=1-3&keywords=raspberry+pi) could do, provided you have a spare SD card and phone charger.